# Index match with if

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, match

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently I am getting the correct answer but I cant keep this part in the code as it is unreliable looking up a specific cell reference

```
IF('Date of Last Turn'!C79>='Date of Last Turn'!E79
```

This is the whole piece of code

```
{=IF('Date of Last Turn'!C79>='Date of Last Turn'!E79,
     INDEX('All Data'!$E$3:$E$5000,
           MATCH(2,1/(($H$5='All Data'!$D$3:$D$5000)*($G11='All Data'!$C$3:$C$5000)))),
     INDEX('Date of Last Turn'!F8:F4978,
           MATCH(2,1/(($H$5='Date of Last Turn'!B8:B4978)*($G11='Date of Last Turn'!A8:A4978)))))}
```

If anyone could help with this it would be very helpful I have tried a couple of different ways of including the match and index but I keep getting error messages

[image: Date of Last Turn] - Date of last turn (Columns C & D are formula)

[image: All Data] - All Data

[image: Answer Sheet] - Answer Sheet

Comment: Why exactly is it unreliable looking up a specific cell reference? Can you fix the column/row or both to solve the problem?

Comment: Can you be more specific.  Why is it unreliable? With what would you want to replace it?

Comment: @ScottCraner I wont be the only person using this spreadsheet so if someone adds in a row etc and don't understand the code they could cause problems with the whole spreadsheet so I would rather it complete it via look ups and look for the info in H5 and G11 (this information also changes) rather than cell specific but if I cant find any other way round it all I can do Is lock everything down

Comment: Given that we don't know how your data is laid out, it's very difficult to make useful suggestions. You need to include more information in your question.

Comment: @AlexisOlson I will try and update my question with images which might help explain its difficult to explain really

Comment: @AlexisOlson I have updated with images of my sheets

Comment: I think the error messages are caused by the fact that you try using two different array formulas in one. Try to split it into several cells: one with `{=INDEX('All Data'!$E$3:$E$5000, MATCH(2,1/(($H$5='All Data'!$D$3:$D$5000)*($G11='All Data'!$C$3:$C$5000))))}`, other with `{=INDEX('Date of Last Turn'!F8:F4978, MATCH(2,1/(($H$5='Date of Last Turn'!B8:B4978)*($G11='Date of Last Turn'!A8:A4978)))}` and then put them together using `IF('Date of Last Turn'!C79>='Date of Last Turn'!E79,PART_ONE,PART_TWO)`. If this still does not work, then you can at least see where is your error hidden.

Comment: In other words, it is a very good practice to use named cells and to split complex formulas into simpler ones and do the calculation 'per partes', so to say. It is much easier to spot errors.

Comment: @V.K. thanks that proves that it works in that form but I need to make the beginning part 'code' IF('Date of Last Turn'!C79>='Date of Last Turn'!E79 'code' into an index match... that's the part I keep messing up and where it seems to fail... I had initially tried named ranges in this document but because ive inherited it theres a lot of hidden vba that keeps messing up what im doing so its a lot of trial and error

Comment: Unfortunately I still do not understand what you try to achieve with your formula. And the formula probably has some broken logic, which is leading us in wrong direction... Could you try to describe in words, what do you want to get as the result?

Comment: @V.K. I have posted the answer below a fresh look this morning and I seem to have got it doing what I needed it to do think it was just looking at it too long yesterday I was putting myself round in circles

Answer (score 0):

For some of the errors, it also looks like the FALSE portion of IF's Ranges (such as 'Date of Last Turn'!A8:A4978) should be locked. Thinking of this since the TRUE portion of IF uses locked ranges.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have it doing what I want to now using index and match

```
     =IF(INDEX('Date of Last Turn'!$C$3:$C$5016,MATCH(2,1/(($M$5='Date of Last Turn'!$B$3:$B$5016)*($L8='Date of Last Turn'!$A$3:$A$5016))))>=INDEX('Date of Last Turn'!$E$3:$E$5016,MATCH(2,1/(($M$5='Date of Last Turn'!$B$3:$B$5016)*($L8='Date of Last Turn'!$A$3:$A$5016)))),INDEX('All Data'!$E$3:$E$5000,MATCH(2,1/(($M$5='All Data'!$D$3:$D$5000)*($L8='All Data'!$C$3:$C$5000)))),INDEX('Date of Last Turn'!$F$3:$F$5016,MATCH(2,1/(($M$5='Date of Last Turn'!$B$3:$B$5016)*($L8='Date of Last Turn'!$A$3:$A$5016)))))
```